# How to get a view which is inside a complex ListView row view?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I have a ListView which has been populated by rows containing data using an adapter.
The row layout is of "RelativeLayout" type and contains various view objects, the id of one of them is "@+id/bar_fill".

I have a loop running over all the childs of the ListView, and I want to "get" the view item i mentioned above.

The code I'm using is:

```
ListView list = getListView();
int count = list.getCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
   RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout) list.getChildAt(i);
   View bar = row.findViewById(R.id.bar_fill);         
}
```

However when it reaches the last line it crashes. When I commented it out and did

```
System.out.println(findViewById(R.id.bar_fill));
```

It returned nulls.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

overide this function in custom adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent);
View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(id, null);
    }
```

Now like if you want certain textview from the listview row item then do it like this:

```
TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(com.pis.prototype.R.id.TextView01);
```

t1 is your required view now...:P

Comment: This is the right idea, but you should use a ViewHolder as illustrated here to avoid the extra findViewById calls when convertView != null. On many devices it can make a significant difference in performance: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to get the already updated/created items in the list view and want to get some view from some row. Then do it like this..:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < yourCustomAdapter.size(); i++) {

        View viewRow = listViewParts.getChildAt(i);

        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) viewRow
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        yourCustomAdapter.get(i).attachmentCheck = chkBox
                .isChecked();
    }
```

In the above case I have extracted the checkbox views from the listview.