# java android, visibility of a button in a list view (without cliking)

Tags: java, android, listview, button

I searched a lot the internet looking for an answer but couldnt find it...so here is my question :

I have a listView, and some rows of this listView require a button. 
So I told myself, okay, i'm gonna put a button in every row (i'm using a simple adapter, so the shape of each row is in an extra .xml file), put them all INVISBLE, and then, when a row needs it, make the button VISIBLE.

The problem is, how to acces the button which is in a xml file that is loaded in the simple adapter?? 
(and WITHOUT CLICKING ON IT!! I saw a lot of answers implying cliking on it to get the view, and then do what you like, yeah okay, but what if i want to control it without cliking it?? how to get the view??)

thanks a lot in advance and sorry if the question has already been asked!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use the **id of the Button** which is in XML, to access it.

```
<Button android:id= @+id/Button_1
</Button>
```

**2.** If you are using Dynamic button, stil you can assign id to it programmatically,

```
Button butt = new Button();
  butt.setId(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom adapter that extends the simple adapter, and override `getView`..
this link may help http://android-apps-blog.blogspot.it/2011/04/how-to-create-listview-with-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same kinda thing before. I used Spinner instead Button. You can take a look at my answer in this link:

[How to get a view which is inside a complex ListView row view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177995/how-to-get-a-view-which-is-inside-a-complex-listview-row-view/8178069#8178069)

This would help you...;)

Cheers